# SQL View From a View Running Slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I created a view that pulls data from another view and it is running extremely slow.  The original view runs fine so I'm not sure what the hold up would be.  Is this typically an issue when querying off a view?

Comment: Please include the execution plan in your question.

Comment: Nested views generally have a habit of performing badly. You'd likely be better rewriting the definition of the other view inside this one.

Comment: Also, if you could post the view query AND the view that queries from the view would help more too.  Edit your original post with additional support details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is nested view a good database design?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5487/is-nested-view-a-good-database-design)

Comment: Yeah nested views are just truly evil. Seem so logical but it totally destroys your execution plan. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/

Answer (score 0):

I did some brief research and can conclude that you'll have a hard time maintaining efficient nested views. In short, your SQL Server query optimizer is going to have a near-impossible time figuring out how to quickly execute your query. At best it has to execute three statements: Source statement, View 1, View 2 (Nested). Without indexes on the tables and views performance is going to continually be slow because it's running so many operations.

You'd be much better off by searching for an alternate solution to your nested view, such as replicating your `SELECT` statement from your first view within your nested view. The duplication is also less than ideal, but it means that your optimizer won't have to work so hard. You can also look into [applying indexes to your views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-2017). When done properly, you will improve `SELECT` performance while sacrificing speed when you perform `INSERT` operations. This should be done if you don't expect your source table to change too often, but is probably the best solution available if you can't restructure view layout.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you use some filters on both internal (fast) and external (slow) views.
Make sure that filters used on the external view are best 'linked' to the internal view. Best 'linked' means that if e.g. at the external view you use some more tables and join the internal view, try to join with filter columns as well or with the lower detail base table.